# How to continue development of an Android Studio x64 project on a 32bit system?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to continue development of a project I started in Android Studio on a x64 pc in a x86 pc, but I'm running into troubles I think may be related to this change (gradle for project doesn't compile).
Files were transfered from 1 pc to another through git repo created by AS, so all essential files (I imagine) are there. I tried searching for answers but at best could only find code excerpts that didn't work and weren't even followed by an explanation of why they should.
I'd like to know if this migration is possible (really seems like it should) and what may be the possible mistakes in my ways.
Both versions of AS are the same btw.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not true, All project can run in x64 & x86. the problem is SDK version and AS version.I handle my project between 32bit and 64bit, its work good.
**BUT** in change place the project in systems u need to update to top version AS and plugins

**Post your Errors**

GoodLuck

Comment: I don't even remember what was the error, but I do know that I eventually got it to compile, so it was probably an error of mine which led to my panicking question.